# socket-io not connecting in Vite React app

Tags: reactjs, websocket, socket.io, vite

Having trouble getting socket io to connect with a new Vite app. I have gotten this working using the same code, with Create React App

Server:

```
const app = express();
app.use(cors());

const server: http.Server = http.createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server);

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("connected");
});
```

client:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const socket = io("/");
  }, []);
```

The useEffect is on a main page in the app, and is definitely being called, but the console log in my server file never gets called. (Server is definitely running)

My vite config looks like this, in case it matters:

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    port: 3000,
    proxy: {
      "/api": {
        target: "http://localhost:5000",
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to pass in `"http://localhost:5000"` (where my server is) to the client `io` call and it now works. The reason this wasn't needed when I used Create React App, was because my proxy was already set to `"http://localhost:5000"`. Proxys are unfortunately set up differently in Vite.